# How to insert last element using myStringList

Tags: java

I'm having issues with `myStringList.insertLast(name)`
I'm unsure if I need to change `.insertLast` to something else. The error says the name cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
public class TestLinkedList
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {  

  // define an Integer linked list MyIntList
  LinkedListClass<Integer> MyIntegerList = new LinkedListClass<Integer>();

  // intitialize the list
  MyIntegerList.initializeList(); 

  // insert a last element 5, then 6, and 7
  MyIntegerList.insertLast(5);
  MyIntegerList.insertLast(6);
  MyIntegerList.insertLast(7);

  // print the list
  MyIntegerList.print();  


   // insert first element 8
   MyIntegerList.insertFirst(11);

   // print the list 
   MyIntegerList.print(); 


  // define a String linked list MyStringList
  LinkedListClass<String> MyStringList = new LinkedListClass<String>();


  // initialize the list
  MyStringList.initializeList();  

  // insert last element Chris ,then Tom, and Bo
  MyStringList.insertLast(Chris);
  MyStringList.insertLast(Tom);
  MyStringList.insertLast(Bo);

  // print the list
  MyStringList.print();

  // insert first element Bo
  MyStringList.insertFirst(Anna);

  // print the list  
  MyStringList.print();


  }
}
```

The actual errors Im receiving say the following:

```
4 errors found:
File: C:\Users\GreatOne\Desktop\Master Folder\LinkedList\LinkedList\TestLinkedList.java  [line: 36]
Error: Chris cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\GreatOne\Desktop\Master Folder\LinkedList\LinkedList\TestLinkedList.java  [line: 37]
Error: Tom cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\GreatOne\Desktop\Master Folder\LinkedList\LinkedList\TestLinkedList.java  [line: 38]
Error: Bo cannot be resolved to a variable
File: C:\Users\GreatOne\Desktop\Master Folder\LinkedList\LinkedList\TestLinkedList.java  [line: 44]
Error: Bo cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: A string literal in java must be enclosed in " otherwise it will be treated as a variable. "Chris", "Tom" and "Bo".

Comment: ah, I should have known that. thanks @ arynaq

Answer (score 0):

String must b enclosed between double-quotes ("). Solution of your compilation problems would be here:

```
  MyStringList.insertLast("Chris");
  MyStringList.insertLast("Tom");
  MyStringList.insertLast("Bo");

  ...

  // insert first element Bo
  MyStringList.insertFirst("Anna");
```

Answer (score 0):

Name are String, In java you have to use " ".

```
   MyStringList.insertLast("Chris");
   MyStringList.insertLast("Tom");
   MyStringList.insertLast("Bo");  
   MyStringList.insertFirst("Anna");
```